# How can I meet the world's most jovial taxi driver?

Tags: turkey, taxis, guides

I'm a fan of Anthony Bourdain's TV shows and the two times he's been to Istanbul he was driven and shown around by the tirelessly cheerful and voluble taxi driver/entertainer Issam (Ihsan ? Isham ? can't figure out what his name actually is).

[image: This fine gentleman]

Where and how can I meet this fine gentleman ? Was his appearance only for the show or can anyone be driven and guided through Istanbul like that ?

Comment: I'm glad you're not trying to [**avoid**](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/53720/is-it-rude-to-tell-the-ice-cream-man-in-istanbul-not-to-mess-with-me) the world's most jovial driver

Answer (score 40, accepted):

His name is [Ihsan Aknur](https://www.facebook.com/The.Best.Taxi.Driver/), and maybe he'll be your friend, too, if you message him on Facebook.

Comment: Good find ! Please expand more :)

Comment: @blackbird I couldn't resist... google Anthony Bourdain Turkey and, bingo. I'm a Bourdain fan.

Comment: I'd love to accept this answer, can you add more detail ? Can anyone arrange to be driven and shown around ?

Comment: @blackbird I would think so, although I don't have direct experience with Ihsan. Film crews do it all the time; you see it with Bourdain, hiring locals for location shoots. Too cool should you engage him. I looked at his FB page and 26 minutes ago he posted (I fixed spelling, punctuation): "I'm so busy, no time internet and I'm working very hard [my car] .My webpage need built again and this time I will make myself. Tomorrow I will speak conference Hugo Boss and I'm really excited."

Comment: @blackbird now, if you want, I can reach out to him on FB and ask how to engage his services; his web site is down. How about offering to do his web site in exhange for his services during your vistit?

Comment: This guys is even cooler than I thought ! Unfortunately I'm neither on FB nor do I have the time to freelance his website :(

Comment: [These](https://www.tripadvisor.ca/Attraction_Review-g293974-d6756211-Reviews-Ihsan_Aknur_Tours-Istanbul.html) folks seem to have gone on a tour with him !

Comment: @blackbird I'll message him and ask how one would engage his services; stay tuned.