# Identify location of this Dondurma (Turkish Ice Cream) shop

Tags: turkey, istanbul, locate-this

Can someone please help me identify where is [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lxaR4uNB3U8) Ice Cream seller's shop located in Sultanahmet Istanbul?

[image]

Courtesy: [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lxaR4uNB3U8)

My 3-year old son has seen the video and absolutely wants to get an ice cream from that same person and enjoy all the tricks. I have gone through [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/53720/is-it-rude-to-tell-the-ice-cream-man-in-istanbul-not-to-mess-with-me) and learnt that there will be plenty of such shops all around us when we were there but somehow he is insisting that I want to get it from this guy.

Apparently he is famous because I see him in a lot of YouTube videos but I can't figure out the location. It would be great if we can find his shop, otherwise I am sure other sellers are equally as good.

Comment: Those Dondurma guys should start paying Travel.SE for the advertising :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks like it is on Istiklal Avenue, one of Istanbul's most famous streets that starts from Taksim Square and goes towards the Galata tower. The exact place seems to be in front of a restaurant called Köfteci Ramiz. [Google maps to the correct place](https://www.google.fi/maps/@41.0302854,28.9756009,3a,75y,110.18h,85.59t/data=!3m7!1e1!3m5!1s5D6tiYkoV9W8sLoHSYu5-Q!2e0!6s%2F%2Fgeo0.ggpht.com%2Fcbk%3Fpanoid%3D5D6tiYkoV9W8sLoHSYu5-Q%26output%3Dthumbnail%26cb_client%3Dmaps_sv.tactile.gps%26thumb%3D2%26w%3D203%26h%3D100%26yaw%3D186.3402%26pitch%3D0%26thumbfov%3D100!7i13312!8i6656)

Comment: +1. The case is closed Mr. Holmes. From the wording you've used in your answer, it seems like you haven't been in this shop yourself. If so, how did you manage to find it? :/

Comment: For Future readers, this is no longer the case. I took the long ride to this place and found out that this specific brand's stall has moved out from this Cafe. Fortunately there was another one over there and the guy looked somewhat similar so we were able to convince our child to still try it and it was fun. Also, they are building a tram track on Istiklal Avenue so it is difficult to walk on and extremely crowded these days because of the narrowed down walk way.

Answer (score 3):

He's in Pattaya, Thailand now on Walking Street.  Very popular with tourists.

Comment: Really that’s cool info. Thanks!